# Find $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $(\mathbb Z_n, +, \cdot)$ has exactly 4 invertible elements and 5 zero-divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $(\mathbb Z_n, +, \cdot)$ has exactly 4 invertible elements and 5 zero-divisors.

As I couldn't find any theorem that would lead me toward a solution, so  I have been trying guessing and checking with no results so far, so I am asking for a push in the right direction.

Comment: Is it exactly 4 invertible elements and exactly 5 zero-divisors?

Comment: @lhf yep! I am sure.

Comment: In this case, $n$ would have to be 9 but $\mathbb Z_9$ has 6 units.

Comment: Also, $\phi(n)=4$ iff $n=5, 8, 10, 12$.

Comment: Perhaps we are using a definition whereby zero is not a zero-divisor.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if gcd$(n,x) = 1$

EDIT: furthermore: Let $R$ be a finite ring with unity, and $x \in R$: $x$ is a unit in $R$ if and only if $x$ is no zero divisor and $x \neq 0$

Comment: @BenMillwood My bad!